# Returning a list

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def foo(*args)
    print len(args)
    print args
```

now I'd like to know how to return that same args list. I guess it should be simple?

Thanks

Comment: Why rate him down? Everyone is new at one point or another. He hasn't asked a stupid question (in the sense that it's inappropriate, or not SO material).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed simple:

```
return args
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) is the Python tutorial: 
There are also many resources on beginners python on the net. Some are listed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774325/programming-tutorials-for-people-with-zero-experience).